# How to write a tool, inverting colors in Windows?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, colors

I read a topic in this site about it, but decided to post another one as I want to write such a tool, but I don't have much experience in C# & .NET, so it could take me too much time just digging the Net, while someone can just direct me to the right library or classes to be used.

So, straight to the point. I want to write a tool that, when activated, inverts absolutely all items on the screen and lets you work that way without torturing your eyes with bright light colors.

Does anyone have an idea of the needed .NET libraries or third-party frameworks, to implement this?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

P.S. Changing to "High Contrast" theme in Windows is not the solution I seek, so please, don't mention it!

Answer (score 2):

Control Panel → Accessibility Options → Display → Use High Contrast.

Give that a whirl.  Sorry it does not answer your question directly but may save you some time.

Comment: Yes, I DID find this solution (SHITFT + LEFT ALT + PRINT SCRN does the same), but what I seek is total invertion of colors. Ubuntu has it with just WIN-KEY + M and OS X with CTRL + OPTION + CMD + 8.